# Scrolling graph of amChart on iphone is not suitable

Tags: javascript, ios, amcharts

I made a combined bullet column line chart. When you travel the mouse icon over the graph, you can see the values of each category. However, I opened the same file on iphone. When I rub my finger onto the touch screen just like mouse icon, graph does not give any responses. But I wanted to become responsive of finger gesture. How can I do this?

I also tried zingChart. Scrolling over screen on iphone is successful than amChart but I couldn't fit zingchart into my situation.

Thanks in advance.
I hope that you can understand my English.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730626/what-can-be-used-instead-of-tooltip-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

AmCharts needs to be tapped first before gestures work. The reason for this is fully documented in the [`tapToActivate`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#tapToActivate) property but bascially it can block page scrolling if your chart takes up the entire screen if you didn't have tap to activate enabled. You can disable it if you want the chart to react to gestures immediately, e.g.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  tapToActivate: false,
  // ...
});
```

To make the balloons trigger by gliding your finger, you have to enable the [`chartCursor`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor) but remove its zooming and panning capabilities by setting [`zoomable`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor#zoomable) to false and [`pan`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor#pan) to false. This will disable the pinch gesture on the chart for zooming, so you will have to use the scrollbar to zoom.

```
chartCursor: {
  zoomable: false,
  pan: false,
  // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6hfuebj0/4/)

Comment: I tried your solution but nothing changed. I have to touch everytime.

Comment: You still have to tap for viewing balloons unless you have a cursor enabled but otherwise disabling tapToActivate does what you're asking. https://jsfiddle.net/6hfuebj0/3/ I loaded this up in android and I can pan without tapping first and sliding my finger triggers the cursor and bullets.

Comment: FYI, I've updated the post in response to the video posted in our support forum as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I give up using mobile. It works on Chrome, Safari or any other browser as my request. Also, balloon texts are moving when touched on smartphone screen.