# How are web developers accommodating former onmouseover or tooltip functionality in touch interfaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Tooltips in the era of touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737773/tooltips-in-the-era-of-touch)
>   [UX Design for Disabled Controls w/ the Touch Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660536/ux-design-for-disabled-controls-w-the-touch-interface)

I've long been in debt to the wonderful [wz_tooltip](http://wztip.info/index.php/wz_tip_4.x_Documentation) javascript library, binding mouseover events to tooltips in order to offer contextual information.  However with touch interfaces on the rise, I am now looking for a better compromise to make the same tips available without relying on mouseover.

I've considered simply firing the tooltips on 'onClick' events rather than mouseovers, and this works in many instances.  I've also considered switching to [jTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/) since I am a jQuery user, and would gain more flexibility with when and how tooltips are displayed.

Lastly, I have considered the simple use of HTML "title" and "alt" attributes, and wonder if touch interfaces expose the information contained there.

Given that I'd like to avoid browser/platform detection, and present one version of my web interfaces that at least 'works' for everybody, how would you suggest I accomodate touch interfaces?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737773/tooltips-in-the-era-of-touch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660536/ux-design-for-disabled-controls-w-the-touch-interface